# How to repair my apt-get

Tags: apt, dependencies, xserver

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with HWE stack (kernel 3.16) on a Dell Inspiron 15-5547, AMD Radeon HD R7 M265.

I've been trying to install the proprietary drivers fglrx drivers in order to be able to switch between my graphic cards. After some trial I found this  [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491) bug. Without, really thinking it thru, I followed the suggestion of comment 24 and run

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

The installation did not finish, but returned in

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 773072 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/drirc', which is different from other instances of package libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now, I want to revert that change. I tried `sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-core`, `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get autoremove`, `sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get autoclean` but what I get is:

```
bruni@bruni-Inspiron-5547:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa-drivers : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri
 libgbm1 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri
 qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri
 xorg : Depends: xserver-xorg (>= 1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1) orN
                 xserver-xorg-renamed
        Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri
 xserver-xorg-lts-quantal : Depends: xserver-xorg
 xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-utopic : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-topic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-utopic but it is not installed
                                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-utopic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Any suggestions, how to clean up this mess?

sudo apt update or sudo apt-get update work normally.

```
Ign http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                   
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                             
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release                       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                             
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages               
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources            
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources              
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources            
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US            
Ign http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages                  
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                 
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US               
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en                  
Reading package lists... Done
```

ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
However note that these are mostly disabled and should not be the problem.

```
ian-berke-ppa-drawers-trusty.list       libreoffice-ppa-trusty.list  spotify.list.save  ultradvorka-ppa-trusty.list       vikoadi-ppa-trusty.list
ian-berke-ppa-drawers-trusty.list.save  spotify.list                 steam.list         ultradvorka-ppa-trusty.list.save  vikoadi-ppa-trusty.list.save
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a mess as you say this must be due to problems in your repository & PPA sources

I suggets to clean the mess first : start with

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Then `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

There, on the file that opens you replace all with proper sources.list generated there : http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ (check all BUT DON'T check "proposed".)

you close the file while saving it.
Then

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

Check : `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Also get rid of the precise dell PPA.

Then try

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If still blocked, You might have to get rid of the blocking package first :

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq 'TheBlockingPackage'
```

Comment: Why didn't you edit your previous answer?

Comment: Is it better to do so ? I should have, then. (used to phpbb forum)

Comment: yes, this is quite different to a forum - we are more about the answers than the conversation. The [tour] may help you here.

Comment: Don't worry about editing this time - the old answer is probably about to be removed.

Comment: @nam1962 The question has been updated after the removal of all precise references. However, no luck.

Comment: Run again the install -f and it worked now.

Comment: However, it did not solve the initial problem...and I made the mistake to reboot....leaving me with an unbootable system...

Comment: If you can get to the terminal with ctrl-alt-F1 or F2 try to get rid of the prop drivers : sudo apt-get purge fglrx* - sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core - sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

Comment: I did try that, however I had not even a terminal access anymore. Anyway, I did a clean reinstall in the meantime (I have to say that keeping an old encrypted home after a fresh install is handled way more elegantly and straightforward in e.g. openSUSE). I keep regular backups of the most important stuff, so the data loss was manageable. I appreciate the time you invested.